# How to pass function as param to a class's local var

Tags: php

How to pass function to a class as param then assign it to local class's var!

This is my scenario, can this be solved?

```php
<?php
class a {
  protected $var;

  function __construct($fun) {
    echo $fun('world'); // This is working perfect
    $this->var = $fun;
  }

  function checkit($x) {
    return $this->var($x);  // This is not working [ Call to undefined method a::var() ]
  }
}
$mth = 'mathm';
$cls = new a(&$mth);    // result [ hello (world) ]

echo $cls->checkit('universe');  // <- not working as it fail

function mathm($i) {
  return 'hello (' . $i . ')';
}
?>
```

Comment: Should be `$this->var` (missing `>`)

Comment: BTW, if you are want a reference to a variable (`&`) passed to a method/function (it isn't needed here), you should have that in your signature (`__construct(&$fun){` rather then in the call (`new a(&$mth)`

Comment: I'd try `$fun = $this->var; return $fun($x);` since I don't trust the PHP parser one bit.

Comment: edited the $this->var sorry typo!

Comment: @melpomene, it works fine, but I wonder if should use that method in every function inside the class?

Answer (score 0):

```
return $this-var($x);
```

needs to be:

```
return $this->var($x);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing something here. From your code you are only passing the address of variable (containing the string "mathm" as its value) to the constructor of `class a`. The reference is saved to the instance variable `$var` (still with a string value). Then in your `checkit()` you are attempting to use the value ('mathm') as if its a function. A function `mathm()` exists alright but not in scope of `class a`. So `class a` knows nothing about the location of any function called `mathm`. Thus the error.

If your insert the code line `print_r($this->var);` inside the `checkit()` you will see that the output is a simple string not a function or reference to a function.

You can use closures a.k.a anonymous functions to pass functions around. Or you can make a class which hold the function `mathm` and then pass an instance of such class to be used in class a.

I hope this helps!